# Error in installing bundle in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, bundler

I am trying to install bundle as suggested in my application . But i am getting the below error as

```
      $sudo bundle install  --local

     /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/requirement.rb:109:in `hash': bignum too big to convert into `long' (RangeError)
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/requirement.rb:109:in `hash'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:675:in `hash'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:32:in `inject'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:674:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:674:in `inject'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:674:in `hash'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tsort.rb:181:in `include?'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tsort.rb:181:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:124:in `tsort_each_node'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:124:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:124:in `tsort_each_node'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tsort.rb:135:in `tsort'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:107:in `sorted'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:221:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/bin/bundle:13
from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

WHy i am getting this error how to resolve this one??

MY GEMFILE IS

```
source :gemcutter

gem "rails", "~>2.3.10"
gem "rack", "~>1.1.0"
gem "hpricot", "~>0.8.3"
gem "htmldoc", ">=0.2.3"
gem "babosa"
gem "thinking-sphinx", ">= 1.3.20", :require => "thinking_sphinx"
gem "ts-delayed-delta", ">= 1.1.0", :require => "thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta"
```

# These should be removed

```
gem "oauth"
gem "oauth-plugin"
# gem "mini_magick
 gem "coderay"

# Needed only when LDAP connectivity is needed
 # gem "net-ldap"

 # Just for avoiding Webrick
 gem "mongrel"

 # For simplicity install this using as it needs architecture of your system
 # sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/path /to/mysql_config
      gem "mysql"
```

Comment: @Ryan - Added the GEMfile in the EDIT

Comment: You should mark that answer as correct.  I patched rubygems using the provided link and it worked great.

Answer (score 5):

You need to upgrade to ruby-1.8.7-p248 at least to have a guarantee to fix it (upgrading rubygems won't work).

More details on http://revision-zero.org/history-of-a-bug